# find the weight of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

**Weight, $W(X)$: The smallest possible cardinality of a base is called the weight of the topological space.**

> Let $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $t=\{\emptyset,X,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ find the weight of $X$

I think the smallest cardinality of a base is $4$ , $β=\{X,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$

Is this correct or i should include also the set $\{a,b\}$ because $\{a,b\} \cap \{a,b,c\}=\{a,b\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. And, no, you do not have to add $\{a,b\}$ to the list, since $\{a,b\}=\{a\}\cup\{b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x$ you only need the smallest open subset that contains $x$, so indeed $\{a\}$. $\{b\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$ (for $c$) and $X$ (for $d$). This will give you the minimal base, indeed of size $4$ as your $\beta$. Bases don't have to be closed under finite intersections so the last fact you mention is irrelevant.